# WebAPI 2 : Default GET ALL is invoked with wrong parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am using WebAPI 2 with EF and scaffolding webapi controllers from visual studio. 
Each controller is created with 4 default verbs (GET,PUT,DELETE,POST) and 5 actions. while there are two versions of GET action.

1. `IQueryable<entity> GetEntities ()`
2. `Task<IHttpActionResult> GetEntity(GUID key)` // default is int id but I changed to guid.

I am using attribute routing and route prefix for the controller. just some fancy keywords for better management of url. `[RoutePrefix("api/v3/Company")]`

Problem :

Ideally when a wrong parameter is sent in url, it should return error, but it is not raising error, instead it fall back to the action without parameter.while if I send a wrong GUID, it shows error.

Like if I call : 
`http://localhost:8080/api/v3/Company/1f7dc74f-af14-428d-aa31-147628e965b2`

it shows the right result.

when I call :
`http://localhost:8080/api/v3/Company/1f7dc74f-af14-428d-aa31-147628e96500` (wrong key)

it set back to `GetEntity()` function and shows all records

when I call:
`http://localhost:8080/api/v3/Company/1` (not a GUID length parameter)

it do the same and shows all records.

I am using attribute `[Route("{id:guid}")]`

Really appreciate if I can get some guidance on this!

Comment: And what route do you have on `IQueryable GetEntities ()`

Comment: @Nkosi Out of box , there aren't any routes specified for default actions. so calling api/v3/Company would simply call GetEntities(). But since i changed the default parameter for GetEntity(int id) to GetEntity(Guid id), i have to specify this parameter explicitly, for some weird reasons it don't pick up anything other than "id" parameter if it's not int ( i don't know the reason).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most likely that the route is defaulting back to the convention-based mapping.
You need to explicitly make apply the route attribute on actions to let the routing know that it is the default route got GET

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v3/Company")]
public class CompanyController : ApiController {

    //GET api/v3/Company
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")] //Default Get
    public IQueryable GetEntities() { ... }

    //GET api/v3/Company/1f7dc74f-af14-428d-aa31-147628e965b2
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:guid}")] // ALSO NOTE THAT THE PARAMETER NAMES HAVE TO MATCH
    public Task<IHttpActionResult> GetEntity(Guid id) { ... }

    //...other code removed for brevity
}
```

Make sure that attribute routing is enabled in the web api config

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Comment: This solution works, but now Put and Post methods are not working with the error message 
"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'.

Comment: @Shahzad, That is because the controller is either all attribute routing or all convention based routing. you are going to need the `[HttpPost]` and `[HttpPut]` attributes on the respective actions along with the relevant route.

Comment: true, I am now using all attribute routing . thanks for your help Sir :)